# Type vs Length/Values in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, types, int, bigint

I am bit confuse between TYPE and its Length.

I have int(4) unsigned , where Length Values is 4.

So Example. INT(4) would display as |0001| ( unsigned zerofill ) where as INT (11) would display as |00000000001|. But the actual number is still stored using 4 bytes as 1.

suppose as INT(4) i have 634567 - Unsigned ( which is Primary / auto-increment id ) store value in my table , then what will be display data of it,  will it be 4567 or 6345 or 634567.

I know How mysql displays data and how it stores it, this are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation says

> This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)
>
> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html